# Why TableView highlight two buttons?

Tags: swift, uibutton, tableview

I have a basic TableView in my application, which display some data from a local JSON file. The TableView has over **50 cells**. To determinate each cell I added a UIButton to the TableView cell and added an Image to the Button when its highlighted. After each tap the UIButton will call

`print(sender.tag)`

and is highlighted with the image. So far, so good. Everything works. BUT I noticed, when for example tap the UIButton with the tag `2`, every tenth UIButton is highlighted too. That means: You tap the Button with tag `3`, the Buttons with the tag `13`, `23`, `33` ... is highlighted too.

I don't have any idea what the problem could be. To solve the problem I tried to highlighted the button with the tag value, but this didn't help

```
let tempButton = viewWithTag(sender.tag) as? UIButton
tempButton?.isSelected = true
```

Little note: Each tenth UIButton has the same value for UIButton and CALayer.

[image: Screenshot]

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let chapter = arrayList[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DataCell") as! DataCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    return cell
}

@IBAction func markingCheck(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.isSelected {


        sender.isSelected = false
        print(sender.tag)
    } else {

        sender.isSelected = true
        print(sender.tag)
    }
}
```

Comment: Cells get reused. You are not resetting your cell correctly in `cellForRowAt`. Show that code in your question.

Comment: Just you have to maintain one index variable in which just store the tag value. Then in cellforrowatIndexPath just check the condition if indexpath.row==index, then write the selection code else write the deselection code

Comment: @rmaddy done, check again

Comment: Where is that original code that sets the button's `isSelected` property?

Comment: @rmaddy added too, but it's in a separate file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the `UITableView` reuse `UITableViewCell`. so when your next items comes up, your UITableView use cell with previous configuration. you have to keep record of the selected button and make it selected and unselected on `cellForRowAt indexpath` method.
if you want to highlight only one cell then you can use a variable to store the `indexPath` and in `cellForRowAt indexpath` set the button selected. 
and if you want to highlight more than one button, you can use a `MutableArray`.